# I want to deploy janusgraph. which storage backend should i use for cassandra. Is it cql or cassandrathrift?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, janusgraph

Problem -> I want to deploy JanusGraph as separate service on Kubernetes. which storage backend should i use for cassandra. Is it CQL or cassandrathrift?? Cassandra is running as stateful service on Kubernetes.

Detailed Description-> As per JanusGraph doc, in case of Remote Server Mode, storage backend should be cql.

```
JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().
  set("storage.backend", "cql").
  set("storage.hostname", "77.77.77.77").
  open();
```

Even they mentioned that Thrift is deprecated going ahead with Cassandra 2.1 & I am using Cassandra 3. 
But in some blog, they have mentioned that rest api call from JanusGraph to Cassandra is possible only through Thrift.

Is Thrift really required?  Can't we use CQL as storage backend for rest api call as well?

Comment: Can you link to the blog post you mention? It is most likely outdated and also there is no official JanusGraph blog so the docs are in general more accurate. Also, what do you mean with 'rest api call from janusgraph to cassandra'? JanusGraph uses Thrift or CQL to communicate with Cassandra and not REST.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you absolutely should use the `cql` storage backend.

Thrift is deprecated, disabled by default in the current version of Cassandra (version 3), and has been removed from Cassandra version 4.

I would also be interested in reading the blog post you referenced.  Are you talking about IBM's Rest API mentioned in their [JanusGraph-utils Git repo](https://github.com/IBM/janusgraph-utils)?  That confuses me as well, because I see both Thrift and CQL config happening there.  In any case, I would go with the `cql` settings and give it a shot.

**tl;dr;**

Avoid Thrift at all costs!